# Failed opening required file

Tags: php

Despite the permissions of  file.php  is 655 and the permissions of the file  application_top.php is too 655 so normally the file file.php can be included in the file application_top.php. But the file file refuse to be included. Why can that happen? The two file have too the same ownership

```
Failed opening required '/var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/includes/classes/file.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/fpdf') in /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/includes/application_top.php on line 333
```

Comment: are you just using include/require or are you actually opening it?

Comment: Check folder permissions and check if the file path is correct

Comment: every things used to work ok until I runed a script to set all files that have 777 permissions to 655

Comment: is it generated from a web page? then check the web server log

Comment: you need execute permission for folders

Comment: @amani, then I suspect that your folder permissions aren't correct..

Comment: yes I know but how can that be if the application_top.php have the right to red from the file.php

Comment: @bansi yes this is the solution so how to set all folder rights to 777

Comment: you don't need 777 permission unless there is a need to write into the folder, just 755 is enough normally try this `$_find /root/web/folder -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} chmod 755 {}`. Warning: this is not tested, just typed in here

Comment: Thx.I have a question if the folder have no 755 permissions the include function cannot be executed since the folder containing the included file cannot be opened is that right?

Comment: I think you are correct. but running it multiple time may fix them. check [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-apply-conditional-recursive-chmod-file-permissions/). the script there may help you. If it is a small amount of folders it would be better if you change permission of folders manually.

Comment: I have changed all folders and files to 755 then with find/exec chmod turned back html,javascript,php files to 644

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your include_path to allow scripts to access folders and files in  /var/www/vhosts/.

Usually it's an apache/vhosts setting, so a little out of your question's scope and this SO category.